# Implementation of the Gibbs Sampler for the bivariate distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, monte-carlo

If I have a distribution where

\begin{align}
f(x,n) \propto \frac{e^{-3x}x^n}{n!} \text{where X is continuous and N is discrete}
\end{align}

Using the example from my textbook (Intro. to Stochastic Processes with R by Dobrow), I tried to identify the distribution for X and N.

\begin{align}
\text{Assume n as a fixed constant:} \ X \sim e^{-3x}x^n \\
\text{Assume x as a fixed constant:} \ N \sim \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align}

I'm not quite sure what kind of distributions they have - I'm thinking that $X$ must be some funky version of Gamma and $N$ some version of Poisson, but I'm really really not sure.

After obtaining these distributions it would be really appreciated if anyone could provide any tips on how to estimate $P(X^2<N)$ and $E(XN)$ using R

Not even sure how to start this problem so any little tips would be super helpful!

Comment: You're right, $X|N$ is distributed Gamma and $N|X$ is distributed Poisson.  What you do is build your Gibbs sampler, generate lots of $(X,N)$ pairs, and calculate the various statistics you want to calculate based on all the random numbers you've generated.

Comment: You haven't completely specified the distribution: in order to do so, you still have to indicate what the possible values of $x$ and $N$ can be. The estimation question depends on how you sample from this distribution.  Please edit the post to clarify these issues.

Comment: As stressed by W.Huber in his comment, there is no answer if the support of $(X,N)$ is not fully specified. Stating that $X$ is continuous and $N$ discrete is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

In this toy example, assuming $X$ has support $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $N$ has support $\mathbb{N}$, the exact marginal distributions are well-known:

1. Since$$X\sim f(x)\propto \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-3x}x}{n!}=e^{-3x}\times e^{x}=e^{-2x}\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}^+$$the rv $X$ is an Exponential $\cal{E}(2)$ variate;
2. Since$$N\sim p(n)\propto\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-3x}x}{n!}\text{d}x=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{3^{n+1}n!}\propto\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\frac{2}{3}\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}$$the rv $N$ is a Geometric $\cal{G}(2/3)$ variate.

Running a standard Gibbs sampler like

```
  x=rexp(1)
  T=1e4;mcmc=matrix(0,T,2)
  mcmc[1,1]=x;mcmc[1,2]=rpois(1,x)
  for (t in 2:T){
   mcmc[t,1]=rgamma(1,mcmc[t-1,2]+1,3);mcmc[t,2]=rpois(1,mcmc[t,1])}
```

produces a perfect fit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From $f(x,n)$, we try to get the kernel for conditional distributions like follows:
$\pi(X|N=n) =  ae^{-3x}x^n $
$\pi(N|X=x) =  bx^{n}/n! $
where a nd b do not depend on x and n respectively.From this we can see that X~$Gamma(n+1,3)$ and N~$ Pois(x)$. Now you need to generate samples from f(x,n). Setting up a Gibbs Sampler (which is a variant of Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm) as follows:

1. Get random initial values for x and n, from say x~Unif(0,1) and n from  `sample(1:100,1)`. (This needs to be tweaked based on how well algorithm works.)
2. Let's propose Xi from Gamma(n+1,3) and accept Xi.
3. Next propose Ni from Poisson(Xi), where Xi is current state of X.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3, each time the conditional distribution Poisson(Xi) and Gamma(ni+1,3) depending on last value of Xi and ni.
5. Calculate effective sample size. I suggest using [R package mcmcse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcmcse/index.html) if you're not familiar with effective sample size.
6. Once you have decent sample size (say 200s or 500s), stop the algorithm.
7. You have pairs (X1,N1)...(Xn,Nn). P(X^2< N) is simply fraction of pairs that satisfy X^2 < N. E[XN] is mean of products Xi * Ni for all pairs.

Hope this helps. Make sure to check that X and N have good variability (good mixing chain). Else try different starting values for X and N.

Comment: Could you explain how you determined that $N$ has a Poisson distribution?  Evidently you assumed $N\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,\}$ and $x \ge 0,$ but then how did you derive its marginal distribution?  Similarly, how did you determine $X$ has a Gamma$(n+1,3)$ distribution?  In both cases you seem to have conflated the *conditional* distributions with the *marginal* distributions.  And could you tell us why it would make any sense at the outset to draw an initial value of $N$ from a Uniform$(0,1)$ distribution when $N$ cannot have any value in the open interval $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Xi'an: Thanks for pointing those out! Haha, silly mistake with N. Removed acceptance probability 1 part as well!

Comment: Can you help me see this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498646/how-to-built-gibbs-sampler-of-mixture-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.